# ASP.NET Core MVC create cascading dropdown lists from single table (Razor)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm first filling `IdDegree` dropdownlist, based on the selection fills the `DegreeTitle` dropdownlist. For example for `IdDegree = 2`, there are 2 in list and multiple `DegreeTitle` (test1, test2,..., test5) of data. So when the user selects `IdDegree = 2`, the `DegreeTitle` dropdownlist should be populated with test1, test2,...test5.

SQL database

| ID_Degree | Degree_Title |
| --- | --- |
| spic | manger |
| 1 | Exm1 |
| 1 | Exm2 |
| 1 | Exm3 |
| 2 | Test1 |
| 2 | Test2 |
| 2 | Test3 |
| 2 | Test4 |
| 2 | Test5 |

Model class:

```
public partial class DegreeName
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string IdDegree { get; set; }
    public string DegreeTitle { get; set; }
    public string DegreeName1 { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,IdDegree,DegreeTitle,DegreeName1")] DegreeName degreeName)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // List<DegreeName> IdDegree = new List<DegreeName>;

        ViewBag.IdDegree = db.DegreeName.ToList();

        return View();
    }

    db.Add(degreeName);
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();

    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));

    return View(degreeName);
}
```

This is the Razor view:

```
<form asp-action="Create">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="IdDegree" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="IdDegree" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="IdDegree" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="DegreeTitle" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="DegreeTitle" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="DegreeTitle" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="DegreeName1" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="DegreeName1" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="DegreeName1" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>    
</form>
```

A lot of YouTube video and didn't fix my problem with single table cascading

Comment: Whats' the issue you are facing?

Comment: I want create cascading dropdown lists from single table

Comment: You want to achieve something, but it is not clear what issue you are facing? What attempt you made to resolve the issue? Did you do any research?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question, I think when you create `DegreeName` item, you want to use cascading dropdown lists to fill `IdDegree` and `DegreeTitle`. I create a demo to show how to achieve it, hope it can help you solve the issue.

I create Model to save the value which you want to select in dropdownlist

```
public class DropDownData
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string IdDegree { get; set; }
        public string DegreeTitle { get; set; }
    }
```

[image]

**Controller Action**:

```
public IActionResult CreateDegreeName()
        {
            var data = _context.dropDownDatas.Select(x=>x.IdDegree).Distinct().ToList();
            var selectlist = new List<SelectListItem>();
            var selectlistTitle = new List<SelectListItem>();
            foreach (var item in data)
            {
                selectlist.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = item, Value = item });
            }

            ViewBag.selectlist = selectlist;

           
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult CreateDegreeName(DegreeName model)
        {
            //..........save DegreeName into database....
            //..............
            
        }

        public IActionResult addItem(string IdDegree)
        {
            var title = _context.dropDownDatas.Where(y => y.IdDegree == IdDegree).Select(x => x.DegreeTitle).ToList();
            return Json(title);
        }
```

**View**

```
@model DegreeName

<form  method="post">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="IdDegree" class="control-label"></label>
        <select asp-for="IdDegree" asp-items="@ViewBag.selectlist" class="form-control" onchange="Test(this)">
            <option value="">Please Select IdDegree</option>
        </select>
        <span asp-validation-for="IdDegree" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="DegreeTitle" class="control-label"></label>
        <select asp-for="DegreeTitle"  class="form-control" disabled></select>
        <span asp-validation-for="DegreeTitle" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="DegreeName1" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="DegreeName1" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="DegreeName1" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>

 @section Scripts{
     <script>
         function Test(a){
            var postData = {
                'IdDegree': a.value,
            };
            var items = '';
            $.ajax({
                type: 'Get',
                url: '/Test/addItem/',
                data: postData,
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#DegreeTitle').prop('disabled', false);
                   
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                        items += "<option value = '" + data[i] + "'>" + data[i] + " </option>";
                    }

                    $('#DegreeTitle').html(items);
                },
                
            })
         }
     </script>
 }
```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Hi @necolas, Can this answer help you solve this issue?

Comment: IdDegree works but when i chose IdDegree  the  DegreeTitle stall disable

Comment: In My demo, Only after user select `IdDegree`, The `DegreeTitle ` options can be selected, Don't you want this ?

Comment: yes I want this but when user select IdDegree, The DegreeTitle  options I can't be select just still disable DegreeTitle  options

Comment: Here I use’ $('#DegreeTitle').prop('disabled', false);’ to remove the disabled property in Ajax success method, Do you add this code?

Comment: yes I do, and DegreeTitle still empty list

Comment: The answer i provided is a work demo, I am not sure what's wrong in your projecrt, you need to  check your project  to find the difference.

Comment: Hi @necolas, Have your debuged your code to find which step caused your empty list?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()Test/addItem/?IdDegree=1