# How to solve Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage<TModel>.Model.get returned null

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have tried to use two select options state and localgovt select options which to select a state and populate local govt for that state in localgovt select option these types of codes working in my project using ASP.Net Core 3.1 but now migrated to .Net Core 7.0 and these types of codes did not work properly displaying error as shown below. Despite my sql tables did not contain a null column, am using json, Ajax for javascript and Installed Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson into the project.

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object       
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage<TModel>.Model.get returned null.
```

***Model Class***

```
public class BiodataVM
{
public BiodataVM()
 {
  this.SteteCodes = new List<SelectListItem>();
  this.LocalCodes = new List<SelectListItem>();
 }
    public List<SelectListItem> SteteCodes { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> LocalCodes { get; set; }

   public int LId { get; set; } 
   public int SId { get; set; } 
}
```

***My View***

```
<form asp-action="Create">
<select id="statecode" asp-for="SId" class="form-control">
      <option value="">--Please select--</option>
      @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Statelist)
      {
         <option value="@item.Value">@item.Text</option>
      }
 </select>
 <select id="localcode" asp-for="LId" asp-items="Model.LocalCodes" class="form 
    control">
    <option value="">--Please select--</option>
 </select>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("select").each(function () {
            if ($(this).find("option").length <= 1) {
                $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }
        });

        $("select").change(function () {
            var value = 0;
            if ($(this).val() != "") {
                value = $(this).val();
            }
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Biodata/AjaxMethod",
                data: { value: value, type: id },
                success: function (response) {
                    switch (id) {
                        case "statecode":
                            DisableDropDown("#localcode");
                            PopulateDropDown("#localcode", response.LocalCodes);
                            break;
                    }

                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        });

        if ($("#statecode").val() != "" && $("#localcode").val() != "") {
            var message = "StateCode: " + $("#statecode option:selected").text();
            message += "\nLocalCode: " + $("#localcode option:selected").text();
            alert(message);
        }
    });

    function DisableDropDown(dropDownId) {
        $(dropDownId).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $(dropDownId).empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="">--Please select--</option>');
    }

    function PopulateDropDown(dropDownId, list) {
        if (list != null && list.length > 0) {
            $(dropDownId).removeAttr("disabled");
            $.each(list, function () {
                $(dropDownId).append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

***ActionResult***

```
BiodataVM model = new BiodataVM
 {
   SteteCodes = (from a in this._context.State
                 select new SelectListItem
                {
                  Value = a.SId.ToString(),
                  Text = a.State
                }).ToList(),
  };
 ViewBag.Statelist = model.SteteCodes;
```

***JsonResult***

```
public JsonResult AjaxMethod(string type, int value)
{
  BiodataVM model = new BiodataVM();
   switch (type)
    {
      case "statecode":
        model.LocalCodes = (from z in this._context.LocalGovt
                    where z.SId == value
                    select new SelectListItem
                    {
                      Value = z.LId.ToString(),
                      Text = z.LocalGovt
                    }).ToList();
               break;
  }
  return Json(model);
}
```

Comment: I can't understand the model design in your `LocalGovt` and `State` model, Could you provide a Minimum Execution  for use to test your code?

Comment: Hello:  **Xinran Shen** See above I made some adjustment so that is more clear to test codes. Thanks

Comment: The relationship between state and localGovt are one to many right? When you select state in dropdown list , It will send the id of state to AjaxMethod, I am confused the SId in localGovt is primary key or foreign key?

Comment: In State table has SId which is the primary key and in LocalGovt table has SId which is the State Id In LocalGovt table that help to query State in LocalGovt table and equally populated list of Local Govts belonging to that State You query in LocalGovt dropdown. Thanks

Comment: Yes, So my question is in your AjaxMethod method, you select related local govts with Sid fk,  why you use `z.SId.ToString()` as the value of options, In my opinion, The value of options should be the primary of local govts instead of foreign key.

Comment: I changed to `z.LId.ToString()` but still the same error above. Thanks for clarification

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254917/discussion-between-xinran-shen-and-dausa).

Comment: I have answered a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75680481/asp-net-core-mvc-create-cascading-dropdown-lists-from-single-table-razor/75681170#75681170) about cascading dropdown list, Hope it can give you some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create a demo to reproduce your code, Finally I modify it to make it become a work project, I will show it below, Hope it can help you solve this issue.

Firstly when I load this view, It shows:

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Then I remove `asp-items="Model.LocalCodes"` from `<select id="localcode" asp-for="LId" asp-items="Model.LocalCodes" class="form-control">` The view will not show this error but the second dropdown list can't show related options as the first dropdown changed, Here is the whole code.

**Models**

```
public class LocalGovt
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string LocalGovtName { get; set; }   
        public int StateId { get; set; }
        public State State { get; set; }
    }

public class State
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string StateName { get; set; }
    }
```

[image]

**Backend**

```
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Drop()
        {
            BiodataVM model = new BiodataVM
            {
                SteteCodes = (from a in this._dbcontext.state
                              select new SelectListItem
                              {
                                  Value = a.Id.ToString(),
                                  Text = a.StateName
                              }).ToList(),
            };
            ViewBag.Statelist = model.SteteCodes;

            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult AjaxMethod(string type, int value)
        {
            BiodataVM model = new BiodataVM();
            switch (type)
            {
                case "statecode":
                    model.LocalCodes = (from z in this._dbcontext.localgovt
                                        where z.StateId == value
                                        select new SelectListItem
                                        {
                                            Value = z.Id.ToString(),
                                            Text = z.LocalGovtName
                                        }).ToList();
                    break;
            }
            return Json(model);
        }
```

**Frontend**

```
@model BiodataVM

<form asp-action="Create">
    <select id="statecode" asp-for="SId" class="form-control">
        <option value="">--Please select--</option>
        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Statelist)
        {
            <option value="@item.Value">@item.Text</option>
        }
    </select>
    <select id="localcode" asp-for="LId"  class="form-control">
        <option value="">--Please select--</option>
    </select>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("select").each(function () {
            if ($(this).find("option").length <= 1) {
                $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }
        });

        $("select").change(function () {
            var value = 0;
            if ($(this).val() != "") {
                value = $(this).val();
            }
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/AjaxMethod",
                data: { value: value, type: id },
                success: function (response) {
                    switch (id) {
                        case "statecode":
                            DisableDropDown("#localcode");
                            PopulateDropDown("#localcode", response.localCodes);
                            break;
                    }

                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        });

        if ($("#statecode").val() != "" && $("#localcode").val() != "") {
            var message = "StateCode: " + $("#statecode option:selected").text();
            message += "\nLocalCode: " + $("#localcode option:selected").text();
            alert(message);
        }
    });

    function DisableDropDown(dropDownId) {
        $(dropDownId).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $(dropDownId).empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="">--Please select--</option>');
    }

    function PopulateDropDown(dropDownId, list) {
        if (list != null && list.length > 0) {
            $(dropDownId).removeAttr("disabled");
            $.each(list, function () {
                $(dropDownId).append($("<option></option>").val(this.value).html(this.text));
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Gif Demo**

[image]